# How to Create a Lesson Plan with Wolfram Alpha

Tags: education, wolfram-alpha

This will be my first post in this forum. I am so excited to see a lot of interesting posting from the community. From the FAQ, I learned that Mathematics stack exchange discussed about mathematical related questions, and software that mathematician used. We think that Wolfram alpha is a suitable topic for discussion because it is a software that many mathematician - both educators and students can use in a classroom.

We are planning to use Wolfram Alpha as part of our class room because it gives a lot of learning potential. A big item in our to-do list is to create a good lesson plan for students where they can explore mathematical problems via Wolfram Alpha, instead of rote processes. We are wondering whether any of the community member have used Wolfram alpha as a teaching tool, and perhaps share a simple quick tips on how to integrate Wolfram Alpha in your lesson plan.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the Wolfram Alpha for Educators [site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/educators/lessonplans.html) and [forum](http://community.wolframalpha.com/viewforum.php?f=12&sid=903fb492180ee5c02ee38a7dfc1cfd96)?

Comment: @zfranciscus: welcome to the forum.  I think questions about using Wolfram Alpha *to do mathematics* would probably be on-topic here, but questions about Wolfram Alpha from a purely programming standpoint are not.  In any case, I think there are probably places where you would have an easier time getting a good answer, as in the links Brandon provided above.

Comment: Even though the question is off topic, I wanted to add that introducing WA into the classroom (and showing the students how to use it) can be a double-edged sword: everyone will love the graphs and the ease of usage, but significantly more homeworks will start having "no-work answers" on them.

Comment: Also, a potential danger: if you do not allow students to use calculators on tests, make sure they are also not using their smartphones to pull up wolfram alpha!